# How do I find CAN bus?

Tags: can

I have 9 pins on power supply unit. Some of these pins are very likely CAN bus. What is a the best way to learn which pins are CAN bus?

It is quit hard to disassemble that power supply unit to see where these pins are connected. I can check voltage, resistance and I have oscilloscope.

**UPDATE**
e.g. Should tester show 12V on 2 pins?

Comment: Probe the pins and look for something that looks like CAN data packets?

Comment: What makes you think a PSU has CAN?

Comment: @JonRB It is very like Eltek Flatpack 48v 3000W. But made by some local brand and AC and DC pins are reversed. It looks like a mirror copy.

Comment: @Hearth I am not aware that that PSU sends packets. I suspect I can send packet to PSU to change max voltage, max current and max power.

Comment: You will not be able to reliably determine a CAN-bus with a multimeter. Use an oscilloscope.

Comment: Identify the power supply and search its mfg's website for datasheets.

Comment: if it is not going to send packets then there won't be a voltage visible as it will be idle. You best hope is to check for the impedance between pins. CAN needs to be terminated at both ends by 120R and if you are lucking this unit includes this terminator (bad if you wanted to use that on a stub...)

Comment: Random power supply.  9-pin connector.  No pictures.  Minimal information.  CAN is a sophisiticated protocol, so odds are that a power supply has CAN is not realistic.

Answer (score 1):

1. Spot the GND wire somehow.
2. Get a scope and clip the probe's crocodile to GND.
3. Measure each of the remaining signals.
4. CAN bus signals look like the pictures shown here.

https://www.kvaser.com/vi/en/lesson/session-1-can-oscilloscope-pictures/

Comment: Yep this is the correct answer. Forget about terminating resistors. It's as easy as spotting a 2.5V +/- 1V signal with a scope - there's no other well-known bus using those signal levels.

Answer (score 1):

It's not a must, but there may be a terminating resistance of 120R across the bus lines.

De-energize the system and wait for it to discharge completely. And try to find a pair that reads a 120R resistance between them. However, this will not give you which is CAN_H and which is CAN_L.

If you need to listen or send messages to the bus then you can go for trial error after to find the lanes after finding the CAN pair. CAN physical layer is safe to connect the lanes in reversed order and it'll not get damaged if you do so. So, once you get the pair, you have a 50% chance of finding the lanes correctly.

But it does not end with this. You still need to know the bus speed (62.5k, 125k, 250k, 500k, or 1M *(the last 3 is unlikely)*) and address format (Base or Extended).

Answer (score 1):

To enhance @Enrico's response:

1. Spot the GND wire somehow. Might as well be bolted to the chassis earth.
2. Identify power outputs. They will have large capacitors - chances are that they'd be directly connected.
3. anything that looks like high-Z or a diode to GND looks promising, like a potential CAN data line.

The [CAN physical layer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CAN_bus#Physical_organization) uses a line that's passively terminated by 120 Ohms at either end, i.e. if there *is* a terminator at all, inside the PSU. The bus is driven in a "balanced open-drain" fashion, i.e. CAN-H only pulls high, CAN-L only pulls low. When the node is inactive, the two signal pins are principally high-Z. But, they might be overvoltage-protected by diode junctions to the transceiver's power lines, i.e. GND and 5V. I.e., when not powered, the CAN-H or CAN-L can measure as high Z, or high Z clamped to some potential... And, a self-respecting CAN transceiver has its reference ground isolated from the main working GND (floating) and this isolated "bus driver island" can have extra two pins for power, often +5V power, as that's the nominal voltage level, if memory serves. (Or there's an internal DC/DC sugarcube to provide the isolated island with +5V power.) So if this is isolated, you may find two or four pins that are floating against the working GND / chassis earth...

On the CAN bus, the PSU may as well remain silent until you send it some command that is recognized.
Actually... theoretically you should get an [ACK](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CAN_bus#ACK_slot) on any frame the listening CANbus node finds valid. So you may as well try scanning across baud rates and basic/extended address, unless of course you know what parameters to use :-)

Not sure if your PSU has CAN or not. I've seen PSU's with the [PMBus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_Management_Bus), which IMO is based on I2C/SMBus.